# PHP Session variable not passing

Tags: php

I need to pass a variable which called 'square' between my php files, and everything is ok until I go to the action file to retrieve data from my database:

```
//plan.php

<?php
    include("config.php");
    session_start();

    $loggeduser = $_SESSION['user'];

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }

    // Get selected square
    $selsquare = $_GET["square"];

?>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 fetchUser(); 
 function fetchUser() 
 {
  var action = "Load";
  $.ajax({
   url : "action.php?square=$selsquare", 
   method:"POST", 
   data:{action:action}, 
   success:function(data){
    $('#result').html(data); 
   }
  });
 }

</script>
```

and here is my action.php file

```
<?php
//Database connection by using PHP PDO
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', $username, $password ); 
$selsquare = $_GET["square"];

if(isset($_POST["action"])) 
{

 if($_POST["action"] == "Load") 
 {
  $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM plans WHERE square = '$selsquare' ");
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  $output = '';
  $output .= '
   <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
     <th width="10%">ID</th>
     <th width="10%">Square</th>
     <th width="40%">Plan</th>
     <th width="10%">Update</th>
     <th width="10%">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  ';
  if($statement->rowCount() > 0)
  {
   foreach($result as $row)
   {
    $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
     <td>'.$row["square"].'</td>
     <td>'.$row["plan"].'</td>
     <td><button type="button" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button></td>
     <td><button type="button" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    ';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td align="center">Data not Found</td>
    </tr>
   ';
  }
  $output .= '</table>';
  echo $output;
 }

?>
```

I need to retrieve all the data that has square = $selsquare but it is not working. The selsquare is working in the plan.php but not in action.php
   Please help me figure out whats wrong

Comment: why are you passing `'$selsquare'` as a string in the query when you have already assigned it. `$selsquare` take off the  quotes and try again.

Comment: Are you getting valid url on your action.php file?

in your plan.php ajax try to change `url : "action.php?square=$selsquare",` into `url : "action.php?square=" . $selsquare,`

Look up php manual for 
[String operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: still not working

Comment: Are you getting valid url? Do you see value you are expecting in url?

Comment: Why you are sending a post request in ajax and try to use GET to get that squrare variable, try to send squrare var as post like this `data:{action:action, square: '<?php echo $selsquare; ?>'}, `

Comment: `"action.php?square=$selsquare"` is javascript but you are refering to a PHP variable. You probably meant to do: `"action.php?square=<?=$selsquare?>",`

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing it correctly. In your ajax method your method of passing data is post and in your action.php file you are fetching it as a get variable.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 fetchUser(); 
 function fetchUser() 
 {
  var action = "Load";
  var square = "<?php echo $selsquare ?>";
  $.ajax({
   url : "action.php", 
   method:"POST", 
   data:{action:action, square:square}, 
   success:function(data){
    $('#result').html(data); 
   }
  });
 }
</script>
```

Now fetch square as post variable in action.php file

I haven't tested the code but it should work.

Comment: The OPs intention (for whatever reason) was that `square` should be in `$_GET` and `action` should be in `$_POST` . This will put both square and action in `$_POST` which (if you ask me) is more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP sessions require a cookie to identify them. You’re trying to run 2 separate PHP scripts (including the script for the Ajax call), so each will need access to the cookie.

Ajax by default doesn’t send cookies. This is a relatively new feature, but is supported in all current browsers.

First, you need to set the property `withCredentials` to true. This will allow the passing of cookies.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: a_cross_domain_url,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

In PHP, you will also need to include a statement like:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

in your responding script.

Alternatively, you can instruct PHP to accept the session id and get Ajax to send it as a query string.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `POST` from Javascript, while in your PHP you are reading as `$_GET`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 fetchUser(); 
 function fetchUser() 
 {

  var square_js = '<?php echo $selsquare; ?> ';
  $.ajax({
   url : "action.php?square=$selsquare", 
   method:"GET", 
   data:{square:square_js}, 
   success:function(data){
    $('#result').html(data); 
   }
  });
 }

</script>
```

If your square has the value ABCDEF, then in your PHP, you will get the request this way

`print_r($_GET);`

```
Array{
"square" => "ABCDEF"
}
```

Recommended way of passing string in double quote is with `{}`

```
url : "action.php?square=$selsquare",
```

Should be

```
url : "action.php?square={$selsquare}",
```